# How to make gspread work in a private google domain?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gspread

I looked in many websites but couldn't find an answer. I followed all the steps of [gspread tutorial](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html) but when I reached the [step 7](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html) asking to share my spreadsheet, I received an error message saying:

```
"Sorry, an item cannot be shared outside of [my company name]."
```

My company uses a google private domain (our emails are my_name@mycompany.com and not my_name@gmail.com) so we can't share documents outside the organization. Somebody can help me to find a workaround? I could make it work using my private account though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that I've found a possible solution [here - Using Custom Domains for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en). Trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Google Admin Sharing]

As far as I know, the only way to share outside your domain is to ask the Gsuite admin to allow it.

He/she need to go to `admin.google.com => Apps => G Suite => Settings for <your app> => Sharing settings` and enable sharing outside your organization